# PyQt5: Can QAction function be triggered via QPushButton

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, contextmenu, qpushbutton, qaction

I have created a right-click menu function where all the right-click functions are linked to a QAction

Eg:

```
self.contextMenu = QtWidgets.QMenu(self)
self.contextMenu.addAction(self.actionAdd_Data)
self.pushButton.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.initContextMenu)

def initContextMenu(self, event):
    action = self.contextMenu.exec_(self.pushButton.mapToGlobal(event))
    if action == self.actionAdd_Data:
        print("Do something")
```

Is it possible that I can emulate clicking on the right-click button? Something like pushButton.click() but for the QAction instead.

I have tried

```
self.pushButton2.clicked.connect(self.actionAdd_Data.trigger)
```

But nothing happens.

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: Is that action's `trigger()` signal connected in any way, or are you just adding it to the menu?

Comment: @musicamante I don't really understand, but I don't think the trigger() signal is connected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While using the returned action from `QMenu.exec_()` works fine for menus created "on the fly", the general (and preferred) usage of a QAction is to *do something* when their `triggered()` signal is emitted.

This allows to keep a single QAction that always does what it's been created for, while being able to add that action anywhere it's needed (could it be a menu, a tool bar, or even a keyboard shortcut) without constantly checking if *that* action has been triggered.

In the following example, the `addData()` function is called both when it's activated from the menu and when *someOtherButton* is clicked.

```
        self.actionAdd_Data = QAction('Add data', self)
        self.actionAdd_Data.triggered.connect(self.addData)
        self.contextMenu.addAction(self.actionAdd_Data)
        # ...
        self.someOtherButton.clicked.connect(self.actionAdd_Data.trigger)


    def initContextMenu(self, pos):
        self.contextMenu.exec_(self.pushButton.mapToGlobal(pos))

    def addData(self):
        # do something
```